# How to display an alternate xml value using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, display

Using v2.0 xsl stylesheet, I'm displaying XML as an HTML table. The @required attribute contains "1" values symbolizing that it's required. I want to display the "1" values as "Y" values in the displayed html table, leaving the source XML untouched.

Example XML:
`<table tableName="ABC" fieldname="field1" required="1" />`

Example XSL that does not work as expected, it displays a blank HTML page: 
`<td><xsl:value-of select="(@required, '1', 'Y')"/></td>`

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input XML is

```
<table tableName="ABC" fieldname="field1" required="1" />
```

and you need to print the attributes in a tabular form, you can use the following XSL to achieve the output.

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@tableName" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@fieldname" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@required = '1'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'Y'" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'N'" />
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

For displaying `Y` when `@required` is `1`, you can use `<xsl:choose>` which will allow you to output the required value without modifying the input XML data.

Output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>field1</td>
            <td>Y</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, Aniket!!